# Accepted way for deploying war with context path in Beanstalk

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using Elastic Beanstalk with Tomcat7 to host a Spring MVC application and need to have the container respect a context path rather than deploying as the ROOT project.

What is the accepted way to accomplish this using Beanstalk? We use the maven plugin below to automate the deploy process:

http://beanstalker.ingenieux.com.br/

Comment: Did you get this working. I have a same problem when i deploy on aws. Its not talking the context root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it in the path attribute of the Context element in your context.xml.

See: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html

Comment: That's the approach I was using.  Was just wondering if there was a more appropriate way to do it through the properties and upload process.

Comment: Are you putting context.xml in application META-INF folder or in the tomcat directory?