# How to set an app's context in tomcat?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have developed a JSF web app which is deployed in a file called coop.war

On my localhost the urls are generated with a coop context e.g. http://localhost:8080/coop/login.xhtml

However, on Amazon's host server the urls are generated without the coop context. e.g. http://myappname.ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/login.xhtml

Is there a way to force both localhost and AWS to generate the 'coop' context?

Please note I have little control over how or where AWS deploys the app in terms of file location; for some reason putty doesn't connect to the AWS host (that's another problem for another day). I'm hoping there is some way to do it via a parameter in context.xml. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accepted way for deploying war with context path in Beanstalk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23534428/accepted-way-for-deploying-war-with-context-path-in-beanstalk)

Comment: That solution doesn't work. It appears that tomcat is ignoring the path attribute in context.xml. I have specified path="/coop" (I also tried path="coop" for good measure).

Comment: Tomcat is documented to ignore the `path` attribute in `context.xml`. You need to name your application `coop.war` if you want to deploy it into the `/coop` URL space.